# LESS.php - where does it save the compiled file?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to setup a php LESS parser: less.php (https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php#basic-use).

I've written a basic code from the example:

```
<?php
  require_once 'less.php/Less.php';

  $parser = new Less_Parser();
  $parser->parseFile( 'Z:\home\test1\www\assets\bootstrap\less\bootstrap.less', 'test' );
  $css = $parser->getCss();
?>
```

that should compile the bootstrap.less file from the given folder. It works without error, however I am not sure where it saves the compiled css file? Can I specify its destination? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its documentation, `getCss` does not save the CSS. In fact, the variable `$css` will contain the CSS. To write the value of `$css` to disk, use for example `file_put_contents`. I.e:

```
<?php
require_once 'less.php/Less.php';

$parser = new Less_Parser();
$parser->parseFile( 'Z:\home\test1\www\assets\bootstrap\less\bootstrap.less', 'test' );
$css = $parser->getCss();

// And now to write the contents:
file_put_contents("output.css", $css);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Martijn. I am not familiar with PHP much, so I got a bit confused at this point.